# Factors for NON-cached performance?

Tags: hosting

I'm going to be moving my site to WordPress. It needs to have great back-end speed, as my users will frequently be logging in while on the site (user-specific content, etc). I've looked into managed hosts, such as WP Engine, Web Synthesis, Pagely and Flywheel. All seem to have good caching for the front-end, but I'm concerned about the back-end performance.

Should I go with a host that is built on top of Amazon Web Services? Other than PHP Memory Limit, what other specs should ask the hosting provider about that would effect the back-end (non-cached state) performance of WordPress?

Thank in advance.

Comment: http://wpengine.com/2014/11/19/hhvm-project-mercury/

Comment: Use PHP 5.6 with its built-in [OPCache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php) and at least 128MB memory limit. That’s all you need, the backend will be amazingly fast then.